# Is phalanx damage affected by critical hit chance or damage?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-crusader

[This reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo3witchdoctors/comments/1zsvji/your_pets_and_you_which_stats_increases_pet_dps/) suggests that critical hit chance carries over to your WD pets but critical hit damage is fixed at 50%. Is this the case for 2.1 Phalanx bowmen?

I noticed some Lord Commander Phalanx builds stacking crit damage. Are they misinformed or has this changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Reddit post is 5 month old. Since [patch 2.0.4 (General)](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/13532431/patch-204-now-live-4-8-2014#general) :

> All pets, including Witch Doctor and Demon Hunter pets, now scale
>   their damage with Critical Hit Damage

The 50% cap has been removed and now pets can crit for your full Critical Hit Damage.